# Getting a NoSuchElementException

Tags: java, exception

I've been stuck on this problem for quite some time now,

```
    public static PureMember createPureMember(){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    PureMember pureMember = new PureMember(xxx(nvm this);
    String tempEntry;

    System.out.println("Enter details of PureMember: \n\n");
    System.out.println("Please enter members first name: ");
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
        pureMember.setfName(input.next() );
    else
        pureMember.setfName(null);

    System.out.println("Please enter members second name: ");
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
        pureMember.setlName(input.next());
    else
        pureMember.setlName(null);

    System.out.println("Please enter members address line 1: ");
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
        pureMember.setAddress1(input.next());
    else
        pureMember.setAddress1(null);

    System.out.println("Please enter members address line 2: ");
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
    pureMember.setAddress2(input.next());
    else
        pureMember.setAddress2(null);

    System.out.println("Please enter members age: ");
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
        pureMember.setAge(input.nextInt());
    else
        pureMember.setAge(0);

    System.out.println("Please enter members date of birth eg: 1-31: ");
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
        pureMember.setD(input.nextInt());
    else
        pureMember.setD(0);

    System.out.println("Please enter members month of birth eg: 1-21: ");
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
        pureMember.setO(input.nextInt());
    else
        pureMember.setO(0);

    System.out.println("Please enter members year of birth eg: 1992 : ");
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
        pureMember.setB(input.nextInt());
    else
        pureMember.setB(0);

    System.out.println("Please enter members height eg: 5.6: ");
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
        pureMember.setHeight(input.nextDouble());
    else
        pureMember.setHeight(0);

    System.out.println("Please enter members weight eg: 11.2: ");
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
        pureMember.setWeight(input.nextDouble());
    else
        pureMember.setWeight(0);

    System.out.println("Please enter members mobile number: ");
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
        pureMember.setMobNumber(input.next());
    else
        pureMember.setMobNumber(null);

    System.out.println("Please enter members home number: ");
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
        pureMember.setHomeNumber(input.next());
    else
        pureMember.setHomeNumber(null);

    System.out.println("Please enter members next of kin name: ");
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
        pureMember.setNextOfKinName(input.next());
    else
        pureMember.setNextOfKinName(null);

    System.out.println("Please enter members next of kin number: ");
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
        pureMember.setNextOfKinNumber(input.next());
    else
        pureMember.setNextOfKinNumber(null);

    System.out.println("Please enter members email:  ");
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
        pureMember.setEmail(input.next());
    else
        pureMember.setEmail(null);

    System.out.println("Please enter members price of membership: ");
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
        pureMember.setPrice(input.nextDouble());
    else
        pureMember.setPrice(0);

    System.out.println("Please enter members accessLevel 1-5: ");
    // Should be integer, accessLevel
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
        pureMember.setAccessLevel(input.nextDouble());
    else
        pureMember.setAccessLevel(0);

    System.out.println("Please enter members access level description: ");
    if(input.hasNextLine() )
        pureMember.setAccessLevelDescription(input.next());
    else
        pureMember.setAccessLevelDescription(null);

    input.close();

    return pureMember;

    }
    }
```

I have two menus, a main menu that picks your choose basically of a CRUD program. When the user picks 1 the program prints a sub menu of which types of member to create, when You chose a type of member in this sub-menu this method is called, creating this type of object. But, it won't even let me enter any data  it just prints all the print statements and then throws me this exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
at ie.wit.app.MainMenu.createPureMember(MainMenu.java:123)
at ie.wit.app.MainMenu.main(MainMenu.java:46)
```

I've read the documentation and don't understand, and I got the hasNextLine() from a person previously asking this question but doesn't work for me?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you read the documentation? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next() The documentation clearly explains that `next()` throws a `NoSuchElementException` when it has reached the end of the input stream. You should be guarding your `next()` calls with a `hasNext()` call.

Comment: Just because you have another line doesn't mean the next token is a double...